# I want to change ons-toolbar's display when the orientation changed

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

My code as follows :

```
<ons-page ng-controller="stockController">
     <ons-toolbar class="DCF"  id="stockToolbar" ng-if = "orientation">
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button style="color:white;"></ons-back-button>
        </div> 
        <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >Stock</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

     <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig" class="span10"></highchart>
</ons-page>
```

Controller as follows:

```
if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
    $scope.orientation = false;
    $scope.$apply();
} else {
    $scope.orientation = true;
    $scope.$apply();
}
window.onorientationchange = function(){
    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
        $scope.orientation = false;
        $scope.$apply();
    } else {
        $scope.orientation = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

I just set the `ng-if="false" or ng-if="true"` it works fine, but when I run my code, it does not work, the toolbar forever display.

Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I call $scope.$apply() after I set the orientation but it also does not work

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use the orientation as Boolean type, rather than string with $scope.$digest(); at end of your javascript function. I tried in my local its working.

Thanks

Comment: It works well，but when I change the orientation, there is a error :Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.pages'),could you help me to solve it?